# Troubles with some layouts

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to put 2 buttons and one line separator between the 2 buttons. These 2 buttons and the line are inside an UIView called "customAlert". This is how i want it to looks like...

[image]

Here is what i have tried...

```
let boton1: UIButton = {
        let boton = UIButton(type: .system)
        boton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        boton.backgroundColor = .blue
        return boton
    }()

    let boton2: UIButton = {
        let boton = UIButton(type: .system)
        boton.backgroundColor = .yellow
        boton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return boton
    }()

    let lineaSeparadora2: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        return view
    }()

    customAlert.addSubview(boton1)
    customAlert.addSubview(boton2)
    customAlert.addSubview(lineaSeparadora2)

    boton1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textfield1.bottomAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    boton1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customAlert.leftAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
   // boton1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lineaSeparadora2.leftAnchor, constant: 0.5).isActive = true
    boton1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    lineaSeparadora2.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textfield1.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    lineaSeparadora2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customAlert.rightAnchor, constant: boton1.frame.size.width).isActive = true
    lineaSeparadora2.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customAlert.leftAnchor, constant: boton2.frame.size.height).isActive = true
    lineaSeparadora2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: boton1.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
    //lineaSeparadora2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 7).isActive = true

    boton2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textfield1.bottomAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    //boton2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lineaSeparadora2.rightAnchor, constant: 0.5).isActive = true
    boton2.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customAlert.rightAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
    boton2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: The constrains are not working. For example, the button on the right just gets bigger until it touches the left button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you can't use `boton1.frame.size.width` and `boton2.frame.size.width` as `constant`s for your constraints, because at the time you create the constraint their values are `0`.

Instead, I suggest you set a constraint to make `boton1` and `boton2` to have equal widths:

```
boton1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textfield1.bottomAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
boton1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customAlert.leftAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
boton1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lineaSeparadora2.leftAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
boton1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

lineaSeparadora2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: boton1.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
lineaSeparadora2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: boton1.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
lineaSeparadora2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 7).isActive = true

boton2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textfield1.bottomAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
boton2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lineaSeparadora2.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
boton2.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customAlert.rightAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true
boton2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

boton1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: boton2.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: I updated the values.  I had forgotten to activate a couple of the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

While there are other ways to draw a black separator, the objective looks to be (1) having a horizontal layout of three UIViews with (2) equal spacing between views #1, #2, and #3 along with (3) based on your drawing the same spacing between view #3 and the trailing margin.

Additionally, horizontal width is explicit in the layout. Also, vertical layout is not part of the issue.

The easiest answer is to use `layoutGuides`, as explained in [this blog](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/goodbye-spacer-views-hello-layout-guides/).

I'm not the best with visuals, but let me try. Horizontally, left to right,  you want:

- Leading edge
- Spacer 1
- View 1 (green)
- Spacer 2
- View 2 (separator)
- Spacer 3
- View 3 (blue)
- Spacer 4

Speaking in terms of "4 spacers" is old school. Instead, let's speak in terms of "4 layoutGuides". The trick? Guides 2, 3, and 4 are the same width - and guide 1 is what it is. (At least by your drawing.)

```
// create four layout guides

var spacers = [UILayoutGuide]()
for _ in 0...3 {
    spacers.append(UILayoutGuide())
}

// line up all views & spacers horizontally

spacer[0].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacer[0].trailingAnchor).isActive = true
spacer[1].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
separatorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacer[1].trailingAnchor).isActive = true
spacer[2].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
blueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacer[2].trailingAnchor).isActive = true
spacer[3].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
spacer[3].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

// set the widths of the views, for instance:

greenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
separatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5).isActive = true
blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

// set the widths of spacers 2, 3, and 4 equal to each other

spacers[1].widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacers[3].widthAnchor).isActive = true
spacers[2].widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacers[3].widthAnchor).isActive = true

// since you probably want *something* for a left margin, set the left-most spacer to an explicit width

spacers[0].widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
```

That's pretty much it. I've ignore anything vertical, and just focused on the horizontal. The keys are:

- `UILayoutGuides` work *like a `UIView` but without the overhead.
- After setting your leading/trailing layout, define widths. (You can get fancy and work with "greater than or equal to" and priorities also.)
- Set the last 3 of 4 spacers to be equal in width but *do not* set an explicit width.
- Set the left-most spacer (based on your drawing) to have a more explicit width than the other spacers.

Comment: Hi, i tried your answer, but i think it didn't work... Maybe i'm not sure how to implement it in my code, but anyway, thanks for the help!!!